One variable inequality with parameter
Using the power-mean inequality, one can prove that for all $p\geq 1$ and for all $x\geq 0$ we have that $$(x^{p+1}+1)^2\geq \left(\frac{x^2+1}{2}\right)^p(x+1)^2.$$
The wolfram suggests that this inequality holds also for $p\in [0,1).$ Is there any proof for this?

Proof.
Since the inequality does not change if we replace $x$ with $1/x$. WLOG, assume that $0 \le x \le 1$.
Taking logarithm, it suffices to prove that
$$f(x) := 2\ln(x^{p+1} + 1) - p\ln\frac{x^2+1}{2} - 2\ln(x+1) \ge 0.$$
Since $f(1)=0$, it suffices to prove that
$f'(x) \le 0$ on $[0, 1]$ or
$$\frac{2[(px+x^2+p+1)x^p - px^2 - px - x^2 - 1]}{(x^{p+1} + 1)(x^2 + 1)(1+x)} \le 0$$
or
$$x^p \le \frac{px^2 + px + x^2 + 1}{px + x^2 + p + 1}$$
or
$$g(x) := p\ln x - \ln \frac{px^2 + px + x^2 + 1}{px + x^2 + p + 1} \le 0.$$
Since $g(1) = 0$, it suffices to prove that
$g'(x) \ge 0$ or
$$\frac{(x+1)^2(p+1)(px + x^2 - 2x + 1)p}{(px^2 + px + x^2 + 1)(px + x^2 + p + 1)x} \ge 0$$
which is true.
We are done.

can you please elaborate on the assumption that $0\leq x \leq 1$ ?

@Villa If $x > 1$, letting $y = \frac{1}{x} \in (0, 1)$, the desired inequality is written as
$$(y^{p+1}+1)^2\geq \left(\frac{y^2+1}{2}\right)^p(y+1)^2.$$
This has been proved in the answer.
